# UIPopoverPresentationController isVisible equivalent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

`UIPopoverController` has a `.isVisible` property to tell if the popover is on the screen or not.

Is there an equivalent for the new `UIPopoverPresentationController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a UIPresentationController, so it has a `presentedView`, so you can ask whether that `presentedView` has a non-nil `window`.

But the real answer is that you are looking completely in the wrong place. UIPopoverPresentationController is *nothing* like the old UIPopoverController; they have almost nothing in common and they are not managed in similar ways. A popover is now just a presented view controller. Concentrate *on the view controller*. You just dismiss it, like any presented view controller (`self.dismissViewController...`). This is the whole point. You no longer retain a reference to anything; you no longer have to manage anything; it's just like presenting and dismissing any modal dialog / view.